# What is the difference between normal lines and normal to a plane?

Tags: calculus

A normal line is perpendicular/orthogonal to a point on a surface, while a normal to a plane is perpendicular/orthogonal to a plane.

if we take partial derivatives of f(x,y) and evaluate it at a point we can get a tangent plane. Isn't the normal to this tangent plane equal to the normal line of the surface at that point?

Comment: There is a normal to a plane at any point of the plane. So the answer is yes, provided you take the normal to the plane at the point where it touches the surface. Note that $\nabla f$ does not give you a line it gives you the *direction* of a line, which of course, is the same for all normals to a given plane (or which you can use to get the equation of the tangent plane).

Answer (score 0):

The normal line is defined as the line that is perpendicular to the tangent line at the point of tangency.

unique line through P0 perpendicular to the plane.